# Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit Install Freezes

Tags: installation, 12.10, 64-bit

I have a UEFI PC with the following specs:

AMD Trinity A10 Quad Core 3.4 GHz,
8 GB RAM,
1.5 TB HDD.

My problem is that when I boot from the Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit install disc, I get to the EFI bootloader with the option to Install Ubuntu. I scroll over "Install Ubuntu" and press Enter. From here, the screen just goes black and the installation hangs there. I have tried redownloading the ISO, checking the MD5, trying different types of DVDs, but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/44179)?  And did  you download the `i386` version, or the `AMD64`?

Comment: I downloaded the AMD64 version. Unfortunately, I am not running via WUBI (like the person in the above post), and can't see any errors because the screen is just blank

Comment: Hmm...locks like I somehow missed that big guide on that post. I'll try following that tomorrow. Thanks!